# Cross-Marketplace In-App Billing

Tags: android

Has anyone come across any design patterns / suggestions / libraries to cleanly implement a way of introducing in-app billing in an app across multiple marketplaces such as Google Play, Amazon App Marketplace (which now has In-App purchasing as well) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a good source for a starting point but states it is not production ready.

[RoboBilling on GitHub](https://github.com/christopherperry/RoboBillingLibrary.git)

Answer (score -1):

Here is another one that looks on subject - [SOOMLA on Github](https://github.com/soomla/android-store) 
I noticed there is also a [sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soomla.store.example&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5zb29tbGEuc3RvcmUuZXhhbXBsZSJd)

Comment: This project does not (yet anyway) support multiple marketplaces.